# Chart not showing first bar if series has only one point

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I have a asp.net chart with int for Y values and DateTime for X values. If I have only one point in each series the first bar is not shown even though by debugging the datapoint is shown in the series.

If I have more than one point in each series all is working fine. The only thing which is different is that with one series the label for the date is not shown in the X axis, with two point in each series one date is shown in the axis. Don't know if this matters.

**Series with one datapoint**

[image]

**Chart with one datapoint**
[image]

**Series with two or more datapoints**

[image]

**Chart with two or more datapoints**

[image]

**UPDATE**

This is my base table with one row (note: different values than in the question above):

[image]

I add the series for each "Gruppe" manually:

```
chart.Series.Add("Gruppe A");
chart.Series["Gruppe A"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
chart.Series["Gruppe A"].YValueMembers = "Gruppe A";
chart.Series["Gruppe A"].Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 142, 207);
chart.Series["Gruppe A"].Label = "A:" + "#VALY";
chart.Series["Gruppe A"].XValueMember = "Datum";
```

Format of the `AxisX`:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MMM/yy";
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Monat";
```

Chart with missing first month:

[image]

Comment: While your problem is quite clear, I can't reproduce this. Can you share code of a minimal example that shows the problem?

Comment: Can you please provide the code which builds your charts?

Comment: @NLindbom Sry I was ill, I updated the question

Comment: @JamesBlackburn Sry I was ill, I updated the question

Comment: Do you mind adding the entire method you have which includes your chart building code including all the 'gruppes' and also where the data source for the chart is set

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, set the `AxisX.Interval`to 0 when there is only one row in the datasource:

```
if (dtChart.Rows.Count == 1) { chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 0; } else { chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1; }
```

and set

`chart.Series[0].IsXValueIndexed = true;`

Comment: Its good you found the solution. But next time please post all the code relating to your issue otherwise its very hard to help!